# C# Create Dynamic Buttons and onClick Dynamic EventHandlers

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

My program creates buttons dynamically.

```
private void CreateButton(string buttonName)
{

   Color[] c = { Color.Red, Color.Teal, Color.Blue, Color.WhiteSmoke };

   transbutton = new Button();
   transbutton.BackColor = c[2];
   transbutton.Text = buttonName;
   transbutton.Name = buttonName + "Button";
   transbutton.Width = 150;
   transbutton.Height = 150;
   transbutton.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 13);
   transbutton.ForeColor = Color.White;

   transbutton.Click += new EventHandler(transbutton_Click);
}

private void transbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   tbList.Text = transbutton.Text;
}
```

[image]

What I am trying to do is when the user clicks on the button(s) it adds the name of the button into the multiline TextBox such as in the picture above. I created an EventHandler but cant figure it out how to make it work with dynamic buttons.

Comment: Are you adding your buttons to the screen/form? (I don't see a call in your code)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a reference to the button that was clicked right there as the `sender` argument. So...

```
private void transbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       tbList.Text += "\r\n" + ((Button)sender).Text;
    }
```

Comment: It works with anything that fires an event (all windows and web controls, for example). The `sender` argument is always the object that fired the event, so you can always cast it to its original type and use its properties ;)

Answer (score 0):

use button array like this.it will create 3 dynamic buttons bcoz h variable has value of 3

```
public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if( sender == buttonArray[0] )
  {


  MessageBox.Show("hello");
   }

 }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int h =3;


    Button[] buttonArray = new Button[8];

    for (int i = 0; i <= h-1; i++)
    {
       buttonArray[i] = new Button();
       buttonArray[i].Size = new Size(20, 43);
       buttonArray[i].Name= ""+i+"";
       buttonArray[i].Click += button_Click;//function
       buttonArray[i].Location = new Point(40, 20 + (i * 20));
        panel1.Controls.Add(buttonArray[i]);

    }
}
```